# Create a image_pull_secrets in google cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am working with Google composer to orchestrate my workflows.

Because company reasons, I have my docker images in Azure container registries.

I want to use KubernetesPodOperator on it, and for this reason, I need to specify the variable `image_pull_secrets` in this pod to give the necessary credentials to pull the image from Azure container registries.

Before using Google composer, I was using Airflow in an AKS cluster, where I created a registry secret like this

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry testquay \
    --docker-server=quay.io \
    --docker-username=<Profile name> \
    --docker-password=<password>
```

But I cannot find how to add this secret into google composer.

Comment: You can store secrets directly into the Kubernetes cluster associated with your Composer instance, but I don't know if it's recommanded thought.
Also you can use Airflow connexions to store sensible informations.